# UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libm.so.6" not found - Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, fortran, shared

I used to load compiled Fortran executables in my workspace like /data/data/com.example.myapplication but that is no longer possible so went to putting the code in a shared library and using loadLibrary(). I am compiling a simple Fortran function and encapsulating the resulting object file in a shared object library because from everything I've read it has to be that way for Android Studio. However, a problem arises when I start up the emulator and the Android code runs, it searches for required associated libs, like lib.so.6, linux-vdso.so.1, libgfortran.so.5, libgcc_s.so.1, libquadmath.so.0, and libc.so.6.  I'm not seeing these in the Android SDK tree.  If I then add the -static flag to the shared object library build then I get:

"x86_64-linux-gnueabi-ld: crtend.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.ctors' can not be used when making a shared library.  Recompile with -fPIC".

An entire recompilation of the GCC compiler doesn't sound like the best option.  Is there any way around this?

Thanks for any ideas,
Steve